# How to remove an interface from virtual bridge in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, qemu, libvirt

ubuntu 20.04 KVM install

after I added the eth intfc to the virtual bridge I lost my SSH connection to the host. To recover, i figure I had to 'remove' the interface from the 'bridge' but it will not allow me now to remove.

I have tried both commands: they remove intfc from bridge, but as soon as i restart NetworkManger it is added back!!!

```
# brctl delif virbr0 eno1

# ip link set eno1 nomaster
```

I have one ilom conn and one eth connection on this hoist and I am trying to understand how to setup this virtual bridge thing to use with VMs. So that each VM has its won physical NIC. (System has 3 more NIcs)

After I removed the virtual bridge and restarted the server. I see that eno1 is now disconnected.

I am having hard time to get my eno1 back from the ghost of virbr garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not defined clearly anywhere on internet by anyone including ubuntu or, libvirt folks etc. here is how it was done:

this is from console, coz pri intfc was added to brg and got hosed up.
but i think you can try it for any intfc and brg:

> remove intfc from brg: from console, as root<

check your bridge info:

```
brctl show
```

remove from brg,

```
ip link set eno1 nomaster
```

renew IP leases from DHCP and brings the intfc up if you dont do this intfc will re-attach itself to brg on nm svc restart.

```
dhclient -v eno1
```

now edit the networkmanager config to make change permanent: if you use static IP define it here: refer manual for static and DHCP config.
Modify the connection file: remove all bridge references.
add dhcp, in my case.

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections# cat Wired\ connection\ 1.connection
[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=af934694-8e32-3581-b9d9-e89476bd3f70
type=ethernet
autoconnect=true
interface-name=eno1
timestamp=

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ethernet]
mac-address=24:xe:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

(hiding my MAC addr)

Now you can check "brctl show" again and restart NM. things will be good.